# why using this argument to ref other argument didn't support intellisense in typescript

Tags: typescript, intellisense

When I used kind of `this["xxx"]`, it doesn't show the IntelliSense

```js
export interface base {
    id: {};
}
export class a {
    b: base;
    a1<key1 extends keyof typeof this.b>(key: key1) {}
    a2<key1 extends keyof base>(key: key1) {}
    e() {
        this.a1(""); //this won't showing the intellisense 
        this.a2("id"); // this works well
    }
}
```

[image: missing IntelliSense]

[image: IntelliSense from direct type]

When I try to add a class and extends the base
override the type b, but seems only show the key list of the base not base2

```js
export interface base2 extends base {
    name: string;
}
export class b extends a {
    b:base2
    e(): void {
        this.a1("") // only show keyof the base not the base2
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post code as images, explain what you get / not get in text ([ask] and [edit]).

Comment: I'm so curious about this problem too. I've rewritten the example to be clearer. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gWAFBW1MAuKAQwDsRMBfTTAYwBtCBnBqAYVUxymDgEID4A3FSw4AtnAA8MKBAAewCMQAmzANYQQAewBmXABYBLBgG0ARN1MBdAHwAKdSH4BKVJRHZRAJikz5ilVAOOrBwdg54ME4obhw41JrEDMAATgCu1MCaybZRsZzYwIYMAHTitqZgpi4A9NWFRlAA7gkA5MBQxJrtDHqajQbEAOb60AMKtLRGigzQefn1JV7llTXV+g3NyarMjRATc27kQA)

Comment: I didn't understand the issue. It is showing error squiggly line here, as expected because empty string is not a key of `base`: https://tsplay.dev/w1Ax8w

Comment: the main question is not showing the IntelliSense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may indeed be confusing that the type itself works (`this.a1("id")` is recognized as compliant), but not beforehand through IntelliSense.

I guess the allocated analysis resource for IntelliSense is limited, hence it may have more trouble inferring/resolving the potential type.

In your case, you can simplify the type as directly `keyof typeof this.b` to help IntelliSense discover more easily the available values:

```
export class a {
    b: base = { id: {} };

    a1<key1 extends keyof this["b"]>(key: key1) { }
    // Use a simpler type constraint
    a1b<key1 extends keyof typeof this.b>(key: key1) { }
    a2<key1 extends keyof base>(key: key1) { }

    e() {
        this.a1(""); //this won't showing the intellisense
        //   ^? a.a1<keyof this["b"]>(key: keyof this["b"]): void
        this.a1b("");
        //   ^? a.a1b<"id">(key: "id"): void // Much simpler!
        this.a2("id"); // this works well
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgI0wGc8BvAKDisQBMAuOUgXwG5ynzRJY5sAbYkTiZGlavgaEScALyNaDZnFbkxVTAEYAPAGtgATw1xQqJDSF79EdHBgALBEQDaAInwuAugD4AFJYaWGgCU8hzUcAD0EXAAqtIiRAgAtmB8aLb6YHjYEEhEMFCYyDBqwhr4ugZGJsBmFgbWGVmN9o4AdPi+-nCBIaTKpZgATJWGxiCm5j0NNlLAXQYBVX0DpcA+faXhrURtmj4uLkEskRE7cADuuQDk8ER2EBfIAOa2dnjFwHx8jrUkW9QotQAHoAfgBVB2e3KByObHC4SBVDBELe7WGBwQNDhpzRQiuUB0+K+fFKHCYQA)

Comment: great! **keyof typeof this.b** works, thanks a lot

Comment: the other addition question

Comment: Seems to me like it should be a separate question.